# How to make rollup bundle the svelte/store instead of reqiurig it in the final bundle

Tags: javascript, svelte, bundler, rollup

I have my rollup config setup like this. When I compile with `rollup -c` and go inside the build.js file I can see that the compiled code contains lines that `require` the `svelte/store` instead of making it part of the final bundle as shown below

```js
const { writable: writable$1 } = require("svelte/store");
```

Here is how my rollup config is setup.

```js
// Imports omitted for brevity
const frontend = {
  input: "frontend/src/index.js",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "frontend/build/bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      compilerOptions: {
        dev: !production,
      },
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    }),
    resolve({
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    production && terser(),
  ],
};
```

The problem with this is I cannot run this file in the browse because of the require. I want the all code to be bundled into a single file. I have looked up on GitHub issues and found some slightly similar issues but those didn't help. Is there a way to tell rollup that this is a browser build so treat it as such.

Comment: If you want one bundle, how about removing `dedupe: ["svelte"]`?